# Grafana graph value as a percentage of the initial value

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am new to grafana & prometheus. I want to graph the change in a value (here disk space used), but as a percentage of the initial value, which one commonly sees for inflation charts.

For example, this [chart of inflation](https://ercouncil.org/2016/chart-of-the-week-week-32-uk-private-rent-inflation/) has every line starting at 100% at the left, and then each point is the value at that time, as a percentage of the initial value. I want to make a chart like that in grafana. When I change the time period for the dashboard/chart, it should always use the initial value as the 100%.

Grafana v9.2.5 and Prometheus v2.31.2

Answer (score 0):

You could use query like `your_metric / your_metric @ start()`, for example

```
node_systemd_timer_last_trigger_seconds{name =~ "apt.*"} / node_systemd_timer_last_trigger_seconds{name =~ "apt.*"} @ start()
```

and set in options of your Time Series dashboard > Standard options > Unit > `Percent (0.0-1.0)`